# PDF text recognition in WKWebView iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wkwebview, pdfkit

I have some problems with UIEditMenuInteraction in WKWebView which show PDF using PDFKit (as far as I know) - when text is selected, there is no copy/paste buttons on iOS 16.1 or higher (works on 16.0 perfectly). Also I've noticed that selection blue view take less space than actual text is on iOS 17. In Files App on iPhone it works as intended.

How I can fix this?

[image]

p.s. I already know PDFKit can treat PDF files like images, but on view hierarchy there is no differences between 16 and 17 iOS but PDFHostView appearing outside of hierarchy in iOS 17.